# get dataItem from asp.net repeater and display on frontend code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont do asp.net so this is a learning curve for me and a little stuck with something that i know should be easy if you know how so apologies in advance:

Below is the C#:

```
rptListingAllMandatoryCourses.DataSource = listingAllMandatoryCourses();
rptListingAllMandatoryCourses.DataBind();

public DataSet listingAllMandatoryCourses()
    {
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        User user = (User)Context.Items["CurrentUser"];

        SqlConnection selectConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBConnectStr"]);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("dbo.procCataloguesGetAllCoursesByCategory", selectConnection);
        adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // get results
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterByDomain", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        if (user.Domain.Guid != Guid.Empty)
        {
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DomainID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = user.Domain.Guid;
        }
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Limit", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 5;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@FilterByDomain", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Culture", SqlDbType.VarChar, 6).Value = "en-GB";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsEnabled", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = null;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@DomainAdminID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = null;
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Category", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = "Carousel";
        adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = null;

        try
        {
            dataSet = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            dataSet.Dispose();
            dataSet = null;
            LMS_DB.LMS_DB.LogErrorEvent(exception.Message, AuditEntryType.CatalogueCoursesGetCourses);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (selectConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                selectConnection.Close();
            }
        }
        return dataSet;
    }

protected void rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
    }
```

Frontend part:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptListingAllMandatoryCourses_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CourseTitle")%>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Page loads fine with no errors but i cannot see any data.... ive checked the procedure and i can see data coming back for CourseTitle but does not seem to be passing to the aspx template? any ideas anyone?

screenshot with the results when i run DB query in DB

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed this to use ListView instead of a Repeater and worked great!